# Why is a variable declared and initialized inside a constructor treated as a different variable when it's already declared outside with the same name?

Tags: c#, variables, constructor, scope, clr

I was just curious ...when a variable is declared and initialized outside the constructor and inside a constructor if we declare and initialize a variable with the same name is treated as a new but different variable inside the scope of the constructor?

Why is it treated as a different variable and why does the constructor let a variable be declared again when a variable with the same name when declared again returns an error outside the constructor?

Please go through my code. to understand my question

```
using System;

namespace Modifier
{
    public class weird
    {
       //variable name I is declared and initialized to int type value 5
       public int i = 5;

       public weird()
       {
            //same variable name i is declared and initialized to int type value 1
            int i = 2;
            //variable i which is in the scope of the constructor is displayed
            Console.WriteLine("Variable inside the constructor: "+i);
        }

        public void display()
        {
            //display() is used to display i of the class weird
            Console.WriteLine("Result:"+i);
        }
    }
 
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //example object created 
            var example = new weird();
            //example object is used to display the value of i with the help of display().
            example.display();         
        }
    }
}
```

Output please refer to the image.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCJeC.png)

Comment: Why? Because that's the way the language was designed and how the name resolution rules work. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Comment: Nothing weird about this. Every language that supports OOP works this exact way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables have their own [scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/). If they didn't, *all* of your variable names would have to be unique, which would be quite a burden if you were on a large team.

If you want to access a member variable instead of the local variable, qualify the reference, e.g. with `this`.

```
public  weird()
{
    int i = 2;

    Console.WriteLine("Variable inside the constructor: {0}", i);
    Console.WriteLine("Variable inside the class: {0}", this.i);
}
```